# C# WebApi Config File-Driven Custom JSON / XML Serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, customization

We currently provide many services to external clients that all have differing requirements on what fields they do or do not want to receive. Rather than creating custom endpoints or POCOs for each client I'd prefer to work with a single collection of POCOs that contain all the fields any client could need and then omit fields individual clients would not need during the serialization process of the request.

Given that these requirements change rapidly the idea is that an external config file would exist that contains information regarding what POCOs in a request have properties that need to be hidden based on a set of keys (such as client ids that would be provided to the serializer during each request). We'd prefer a config file so we don't have to recompile / redeploy service code each time a client changes their mind (something we can't control).

Aside from creating a custom serializer (and essentially leveraging a similiar idea to the 'JsonIgnore / IgnoreMember' paradigm) is there any established standard library or pattern for handling this sort of problem? I feel like people must have encountered it before.

Comment: I'm not sure if this may fit your requirements, but have you looked into [Breeze.js](http://www.getbreezenow.com/breezejs)?

Comment: @Brett This change is a purely server-side requirement - we won't have any control of how our clients consume the information so something like breeze.js wouldn't be helpful in this context. Appreciate the reply however!